# ClosedXml InsertTable with IEnumerable property

Tags: c#, generic-list, closedxml

Have taken over a legacy project which uses ClosedXML. The method that creates an error takes an a

```
IEnumerable<MainObject> rows
```

and create a worksheet of it. But there exists a property of another

```
IEnumerable<Object1>
```

in MainObject. The code executes this by

```
                worksheet.Cell(startRow, 1).InsertTable(rows);
```

And when doing that that i get

```
An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to set cell value to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Object1]
System.ArgumentException: Unable to set cell value to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Object1]
```

My guess is that I have to create another (overridden?) InsertTable that uses reflection to call correct types and then even uses InsertTable on the IEnumerable property. 
But it would be possible to use some kind of recursive call in the overridden function and skip all the custom mapping?

Any idea or suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClosedXML doesn't know how to handle the inner `Object1` on each row. It's easier if you create your own `IEnumerable<>` of your own POCO objects and call the `InsertTable` on that, e.g.

```
var pocos = rows.Select(m => new { m.Property1, m.Property2, m.Object1.OtherProperty });
worksheet.Cell(startRow, 1).InsertTable(pocos);
```